# Opening files through iteration

Tags: c++, c, text-files

There are about 50 files that need to be opened in my program for reading and i renamed all of them from 1.txt to 50.txt hoping i can pass the filename through a loop that increments the file number, but i don't know how / don't think it is possible to pass an integer to the char or is there a better way to workaround my situation.

```
char* filename = "";

for(int i =0; i < 50; i++)
{
if(i == 0){filename = "0.txt";}
if(i == 1){filename = "1.txt";} // ..
int num = 0, theinteger = 0;
ifstream in(filename, ios::binary);
unsigned char c;
while( in.read((char *)&c, 1) )
{       
        in >> theinteger;
        sca.chac[num]=theinteger; 
        num++;
}
}

return 0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a relatively straightforward way to do it - in C, use [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) function, like this:

```
char filename[100];
sprintf(filename, "%d.txt", i);
```

In C++, use [`ostringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostringstream/):

```
ostringstream oss;
oss << i << ".txt";
```

Comment: I got errors passing oss to the char, the string and directly in ifstream, how do i pass it?

Answer (score 3):

Just build the string representing the name of the file you have to open with one of the following:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << anIntVal;
mystring = ss.str() + ".txt";
```

or

```
mystring = boost::lexical_cast<string>(anIntVal);
mystring += ".txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) function. It works just like the printf function but it prints to a `char*`. You have to make sure though that the `char*` is large enough (number of characters you need plus 1 for the NULL terminator).
You can then increment the filenumber in the for loop and use the sprintf function to update the `char* filename`, and then open the file.

In your case:

```
char* filename[10];
int i;
for( i = 0; i <= 50; ++i){
    sprintf(filename,"%i.txt",i);
    //do stuff with the files
}
```

I find it useful (for nice sorting for instance to use padded filenames, this also makes assigning space to the `char*` easier:

```
char* filename = "50.txt"; //the highest number should fit
int i;
for( i = 0; i <= 50; ++i){
    sprintf(filename,"%02i.txt",i);
    //do stuff with the files
}
```

Hope this helps you!